# Heroku - environment variable for Srping Boot DB connect

Tags: spring, heroku, environment-variables, cleardb

I have an app on Spring Boot that running in two environments, local and heroku:

1. Local - connect to DB is configured by app.properties.
2. Heroku - app is working w\o app.properties, using one environment variable:

   > heroku config -a zed-social-network
   > === zed-social-network Config Vars
   > CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL: mysql://{login}:{pass}@host.com/heroku?reconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8

Question: how I can configure DB connect in Spring on local machine in same style, with one env variable?

Comment: I can configure local launch with 4 env variables: 
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME


How Heroku and Spring handle it only with one env variable, this is the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a command line argument:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments=--customArgument=custom
```

so in your case

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments=--CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL=your_url
```

--

Alternatively, you could add the url to system variables and then reference it in application.properties like so:

```
spring.datasource.url=${NAME_OF_THE_SYSTEM_VARIABLE}
```

Comment: Thx for answer, but the thing is that I can configure app working locally only with 4 env variables (SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL, SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME, SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD, SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME) and I cant do it with only one env variable, like Heroku does.

Comment: what stoppping you from creating one env variable which has a complete url value with login and password?

Comment: Bad syntax lol. I was trying to do same thing tomorrow, but have mistakes in URL. Now it works :)
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://LOGIN:PASS@localhost:3306/social
And it works w\o any params in application.properties, like it does with Heroku. Thx, buddy!